# How to Get Google to Include My Adult Website?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, adult-content

I read online that Google doesn't include adult content, but still a lot of it comes up when searching from adult content, what if I let my adult human products be included?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get adult content indexed on Google. They have a whole page of guidelines for it, including ensuring you properly mark explicit materials for safesearch compliance and allowing Googlebot to spider beyond age gates.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/safesearch

Comment: thank you, i will check that out !